# Serializing arrays as documents in MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class that implements `ICollection<T>` interface:

```
class Test : ICollection<string>
{
    [BsonElement("items")]
    private List<string> _items;

    [BsonElement("someOtherProp")]
    public bool SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    // ...ICollection<string> impl
}
```

By default it is (de-)serialized using `ArraySerializer` class, so any other properties or fields (even public & decorated with `BsonElement` attribute) are ignored.

Does anyone know how can i enforce my class to be deserialized as a regular one?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like i found a solution. You can do this at application startup:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
    typeof(Test), 
    new BsonClassMapSerializer(BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(Test))));
```

I'm not sure, but it might conflict with `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(...)` method call (i.e. methods call order might be important) - i didn't check this out. Note, that such registration is global for the whole app domain. If it is inappropriate, things get a little more tricky, cause you can't just decorate your class property with `BsonClassMapSerializer` attribute. But this is where i stopped my little research, cause i achieved my goal.

I hope someone will find this answer helpful!